# Inverse of nonsquare matrix product

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a $n\times m$ matrix, $C$, and a $m\times m$ matrix, $B$. Is there any computational trick that allows me to calculate $(CBC^T)^{-1}$ without first calculating $Z=CBC^T$? Specifically, when $m<<n$, I want to avoid storing the $n\times n$ matrix $Z$.

This reminds me of the Sherman-Woodbury-Morrison Identity for $(A+CBC^T)^{-1}$ if $A$ were a matrix of zeros, however, because $A$ would have no inverse, this doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: We have $(CBC^T)^{-1} = [C^{-1}]^TB^{-1}C^{-1}$, so it suffices to calculate the inverses separately. Does that help?

Comment: Note that if $m < n$, then $Z$ will necessarily fail to be invertible. Are you interested in calculating a pseudoinverse of $Z$?

Comment: Why is $Z$ non-invertable for $m<n$?

Comment: Because the rank of a product $ABC$ is at most equal to the minimum of the ranks of $A,B,C$. Beccause $B$ has rank at most $m$, $Z = CBC^T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with rank at most $m < n$.